# Split http Response into different Observables

Tags: angular, http

I want to split a http response into different Variables/Observables.

The reponse is a Json:

```
[
  {
    "status": [
        { "id": 1, "value": "active"},
        { "id": 2, "value": "inactive"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": [
        { "id": 1, "value": "full"},
        { "id": 2, "value": "half"}
    ]
  }
]
```

Here i want to split the response into 2 different Observables.

**test.service.ts**

```
status$: Observable<DropdownOption[]> = new Observable();
type$: Observable<DropdownOption[]> = new Observable();

constructor(private http: Http) {
this.getDropdowns();


getDropdowns(): void {
  this.http.get(this.url)
  .map((res) => <DropdownOption[]>res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    for (let key in data) {
      for (let k in data[key]) {
        this[k + '$'] = Observable.of(data[key][k]);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.testService.status$.subscribe(data => {
        this.status = data;
    });
}
```

**Error:** TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

If i log the component, i see that the variable status$ is filled:
status$: ScalarObservable {_isScalar: true, value: Array(2), scheduler: null}

How can i avoid the error and get things working?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
getDropdowns(): Observable<MyType> { //Return the observable
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map((res) => <MyType>res.json());        
}

let response: Observable<MyType> = getDropdowns().publishReplay(1).refCount();// Cache the reponse
status$: Observable<DropdownOption[]> = response.map(x => x[0].status)//map to get the status
type$: Observable<DropdownOption[]> = response.map(x => x[1].type)//map fot the type
```

Comment: Okay, that worked this way. I did not hear anything about publishReplay until now. 
I use an Interface: export interface DropdownOption { id:  number, value: string } That does not match now (Property status does not exist), you have also a hint for me?

Comment: You need to create a object where I use `MyType` are use `any`. You can use `DropdownOption ` because it does not match your response.

Answer (score 0):

try like this to avoid the error :

**service.ts**

```
getDropdowns(): void {
    this.http.get(this.url)
        .map((res) => {
            let data = <DropdownOption[]>res.json();
            for (let key in data) {
                for (let k in data[key]) {
                    return this[k + '$'] = Observable.of(data[key][k]);
                }
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Did not solve the problem. Same error, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be useful to know **WHY** you want to split it into 2 observables, since you only call one.

But if you want to do so, you should use Subjects and Observables :

```js
private sub1: Subject<any> = new Subject();
private sub2: Subject<any> = new Subject();
private obs1: Observable<any> = this.sub.asObservable();
private obs2: Observable<any> = this.sub.asObservable();

yourFunction(): any {
  this.myHttpCall().subscribe(data => {
    this.sub1.next(data.data1);
    this.sub2.next(data.data2);
  });
}

// In your components

this.myService.obs1.subscribe(data1 => {});
this.myService.obs2.subscribe(data2 => {});
```

Comment: Of course, i use the other Observable in another component.
This was just an example.

Comment: Then make 2 endpoints ? Anyways, this code should do the trick for you.